# How can I convert the StandardScaler() transformation back to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm working with a model, and after splitting into train and test, I want to apply StandardScaler(). However, this transformation converts my data into an array and I want to keep the format I had before. How can I do this?

Basically, I have:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[features]
y = df[["target"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, train_size=0.7, random_state=42
)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_sc = sc.transform(X_test)
```

How can I get `X_train_sc` back to the format that `X_train` had?

**Update**: I don't want to get `X_train_sc` to reverse back to before being scaled. I just want `X_train_sc` to be a dataframe in the easiest possible way.

Comment: There should be an `inverse_transform` method for the `Standard_Scaler` that takes you back.

Comment: The inverse_transform change the data back to before being scaled. I don't want that, I just want X_train_sc to be in the same format as X_train

Comment: What do you mean by *same format*?

Comment: After applying StandardScaler(), I lose track of the name of the variables. It becomes an array without the column names. I just want a dataframe like it was X_train

Comment: Something to realize is that `X_train` is not scaled yet. You are using `fit_transform` that completes two tasks for the data in one step. You should use `fit` separately to keep track of the variables, then apply `transform` in a different step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, applying the scaling results in a numpy array, to get a dataframe you can initialize a new one:

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = X_train.columns
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_sc = pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(X_train), columns=cols)
X_test_sc = pd.DataFrame(sc.transform(X_test), columns=cols)
```

**2022 Update**

As of scikit-learn version 1.2.0, it is possible to use the `set_output` API  to configure transformers to output pandas DataFrames (check the [doc example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html))

The above example would simplify as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = X_train.columns
sc = StandardScaler().set_output(transform="pandas")
X_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_sc = sc.transform(X_test)
```